# How to get the original full command line used to launch NodeJS program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I can use `process.argv` to get an array of arguments passed to the NodeJS program, but is there a way to get the full exact command line string entered on the shell that the NodeJS program was launched with? If not the exact string, is there any close equivalent that can be determined?

Comment: There has been no activity for some time. Can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

`process.argv` is the correct way. As a start, you can do:

```
console.log(process.argv.join(" "))
```

Then you can change paths to relative paths if you wish.

Comment: also `process.argv0` [can be used](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv0) to re-create the launcher...

Answer (score 0):

To correctly recreate the original command line that launched a node process you have to take into account the params passed to nodejs, which aren't included in argv.

Params specific to node are stored in process.execArgv, so to completely recreate the launching command line you'll want to do something like:

```js
let command_line = `${process.argv[0]} ${process.execArgv.join(' ')} ${process.argv.slice(1).join(' ')}`;
```